# What is the cardinality of the set of all subgroups of $S_\alpha$ for infinite $\alpha$?

Tags: group-theory, set-theory, symmetric-groups, infinite-groups

Let’s define $S_\alpha$ as a group of all bijections on a set with cardinality $\alpha$ under composition.

Let’s denote the set of all subgroups of a group $G$ as $Sub(G)$.

> What is the cardinality of $Sub(S_\alpha)$ for $\alpha \geq \aleph_0$?

Currently I only know the following bounds:

$$2^\alpha \leq |Sub(S_\alpha)| \leq 2^{2^\alpha}$$

Proof of the lower bound:

There are known to be $2^\alpha$ non isomorphic groups of order $\alpha$, and each of them is isomorphic to some subgroup of $S_\alpha$ by Cayley theorem.

Proof of the upper bound:

$$Sub(S_\alpha) \subset P(S_\alpha)$$

Thus

$$|Sub(S_\alpha)| \leq |P(S_\alpha)| = 2^{|S_\alpha|} = 2^{2^\alpha}$$

Comment: An easier way to get $2^{\alpha}$ is that each subset of $\alpha$ gives you a subgroup (the subgroup fixing that subset).

Comment: See YCor's answer to [this mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301871). That answer's the question at least for $\alpha = \aleph_0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $2^{2^\alpha}$ subgroups of $S_\alpha$.

We know that $\alpha=\alpha\cdot 2$ (as a cardinal), so we can use $X=\alpha\times\{0,1\}$ instead of $\alpha$.

For each $A\subseteq \alpha$, consider the following permutation over $X$:
$$f_A((\xi, i))=\begin{cases} (\xi,1-i)&\text{if $\xi\in A$,} \\ (\xi,i)&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

It is easy to see that $f_Af_B=f_{A\triangle B}$ for all $A,B\subseteq \alpha$ (where $A\triangle B=(A-B)\cup (B-A)$ is the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$.)
Therefore, the collection of all $G=\{f_A\in S(X)\mid A\subseteq \alpha\}$ forms a subgroup of $S(X)$. Moreover, we can see that the map $A\mapsto f_A$ is an isomorphism between the group $(\mathcal{P}(\alpha),\triangle)$ and $G$, which is isomorphic to the product of $\alpha$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

In summary, our $G$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^\alpha$. [We can see that the dimension of $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^\alpha$ is $2^\alpha$](https://mathoverflow.net/a/49572/48041), so we can generate $2^{2^\alpha}$ subspaces of $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^\alpha$.

Comment: This answers the question, but it is worth pointing out that in the MO post I referred to in my comment, YCor proves the stronger result that there are $2^{2^\alpha}$ isomorphism classes of subgroups of $S_\alpha$ in the case $\alpha = \aleph_0$.